# Error when trying log() transformation of continuous variables in logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

Im trying to do transformations of my predictors in my logistic regression, but i keep getting error message suggesting that i may have an infinite value or something.

```
regTRANSFORM<- glm(DEFBENRP~BLS_URBN+log(LIQUDYRX)+log(ETRANPTP)+log(FINCBTXM)+log(MRPINSPQ)+log(MRTINTPQ)+OTHLOAN+log(EDUC_REF)+log(EOWNDWLP)+log(AGE_REF), data = data_model, family = "binomial")
```

summary(regTRANSFORM)

All of these log transformations are done to continuous variables
This is the error message:

> Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, :
> NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'

Comment: This usually happens with `log(0)` since there is an asymptote at x = 0

Comment: If you don't have any negative numbers you could try the inverse hyperbolic sine transformation `asinh(x)`.